# Multiprocessing connection between two processes at the same time with TCP

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, multiprocessing, kivy

I'm kind of a rookie in python coding and I am trying to learn multiprocessing for a problem that I have.

I have a project with a raspberry pi(linux) and from another PC/device(windows) I am trying to share data between them with TCP connection. I made the server/client code that is working (server on raspberry and client on PC).

Next step is to make a visual application (in this case I choose kivy for that) and directly connect and send data from my PC to my raspberry by this application, PC being the client here directly from python/kivy code.

The problems are, when I connect introducing the IP and PORT in my kivy application the script is connecting me, but immediately kill the server and I want my server to be continuously alive all the time.

Other problem, imagine the server is not killed by the code, in the other function named send_data I want to send the speed and angle variable to my server and still be connected to the server and the server be alive, SO my only option was multiprocessing.

Code for server on raspberry:

```
import socket

host = ''
port = int(input("Port: "))

speed = []
angle = []

def setupServer():
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   print ("Socket created")
   try:
      s.bind((host, port))
   except socket.error as msg:
      print(msg)
   print("Socket bind complete.")
   return s

def setupConnection():
   s.listen(1)
   conn, address = s.accept()
   print("Connected to: " +address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))
   return conn

def dataTransfer(conn):
   global speed,angle

   data = conn.recv(1024)
   data = data.decode('utf-8')
   """ split the data """
   dataMessage = data.split(' ',1)
   speed = dataMessage[0]
   angle = dataMessage[1]

   print(speed)
   print(angle)

   if dataMessage[0] == 'exit':
       print("Client has left the server")
       break
   if dataMessage[0] == 'kill':
       print("Server is shutting down")
       s.close()
       break

   conn.close()


s = setupServer()

while True:
   try:
      conn = setupConnection()
      dataTransfer(conn)
   except:
      break
```

Code for my client with kivy module:

```
import kivy
import socket
import multiprocessing

kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')


class MyGrid(Widget):
    ip = ObjectProperty(None)
    port = ObjectProperty(None)
    speed = ObjectProperty(None)
    angle = ObjectProperty(None)

    def connecting(self):
        h = self.ip.text
        p = int(self.port.text)

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((h, p))
        self.lbl.text = "Connected to server!"

        return s

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__()

    def send_data(self):
        h = self.ip.text
        p = int(self.port.text)
        speed = self.speed.text
        angle = self.angle.text

        s = MyGrid.connecting(h, p)

        var = speed + " " + angle
        s.send(str.encode(str(var)))

        #reply = s.recv(1024)
        #print(reply.decode('utf-8'))
        self.lbl.text = "Speed and angle has been send!"

        s.close()

    def dct(self):
        h = self.ip.text
        p = int(self.port.text)

        s = MyGrid.connecting(h, p)
        s.close()
        self.lbl.text = "Client disconnected!"

    def stop_srvv(self):
        h = self.ip.text
        p = int(self.port.text)

        s = MyGrid.connecting(h, p)

        s.send(str.encode(str("kill ")))

        reply = s.recv(1024)
        print(reply.decode('utf-8'))
        self.lbl.text = "Server stopped!"


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Code for kivy styling part:

```
<MyGrid>
    lbl: my_label
    ip: ip
    port: port
    speed: speed
    angle: angle

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "IP"

            TextInput:
                id: ip
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "PORT"

            TextInput:
                id: port
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "Speed"

            TextInput:
                id: speed
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "Angle"

            TextInput:
                id: angle
                multiline: False

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: "CONNECT"
                on_press: root.connecting()

            Button:
                text: "DISCONNECT"
                on_press: root.dct()

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Button:
                text: "SEND DATA"
                on_press: root.send_data()

            Button:
                text: "STOP SERVER"
                on_press: root.stop_srvv()

            Label:
                id: my_label
                text: ""
```

I want to connect, disconnect and send data through TCP connection, all of them with the server alive all the time (the server should close ONLY when I press the button "Stop server").
Apparently the kivy module have a weird structure and I don't really understand how to assign multiprocessing in my problem AND kivy structure.

Can somebody of you guys look at my code and correct it with multiprocessing to do what I need or at least give me an advice/tutorial or something?

**UPDATE**: I didn't used any multiprocessing code yet as you see, firstly I tried with pool and map to divide the connecting part to one core and rest of them on other, but to keep my server alive I need a loop sequence in the connecting zone. (my laptop have only 2 cores)

Answer (score 0):

Use [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) instead. multiprocessing is basically like starting a whole other process, and it will not be easy to share data unless you write to files. With threading you are in the same process, and can access variables between threads.
Here is a little example of how to implement threading.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import threading

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((host, port))


KV = """

BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: app.label_text

"""

class MyApp(App):
    label_text = StringProperty("")

    def build(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.update_label).start()
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


    def update_label(self):
        while True:
            self.label_text = sock.recv(1025)


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: My first though was to use threading as you but this project is for school and my teacher said to use multiprocessing, thank you anyway for your comment

Comment: @VladHanganu you can use shared memory in multiprocessing. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: That's exacly what I am talking about, I need a code with sharing between datas and corelate them in the code that I asked.
Ideea is the following, I need that to implement that in a code because  in future I need that tipe of code for the project in a different form and the teacher told us to implement that because we will need to adapt later in something else.

Comment: Problem there is I don't know how to to keep the connecting function alive in the same time other functions can take variables from them and eventually close the function when I need. To be more explicit I need to connect, remain connected to the server and if  i want to send speed and angle just send them and still be connected because if I need to send again (second time or third or etc) the values  of speed and angle should be sent again and still need to be connected to the server in all of this time until I press my disconnect or stop server button.

Comment: Anyway I really appreciate your comments and support, thank you!

Comment: No problem friend. I have not used multiprocessing much.